# Java .Net Interop. Axis java.util.Map

Tags: java, .net, web-services, wsdl, axis

I have wsdl that needs to be interpreted by wsdl.exe (.net sdk 2.0)
This wsdl is generated on runtime by axis engine, and it is reading a wsdd file to generate this.

One of my return types have java.util.Map inside and here is the schema for a map in wsdl (just one part of wsdl)

```
<schema targetNamespace="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            <complexType name="Map">
                <sequence>
                    <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="item">
                        <complexType>
                            <all>
                                <element name="key" type="xsd:anyType" />
                                <element name="value" type="xsd:anyType" />
                            </all>
                        </complexType>
                    </element>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
        </schema>
```

But when I run the wsdl.exe to read this wsdl I am getting following error;

> - Unable to import operation 'getXXX'.
> - Types must be declared at the top level in the schema. Please review
>     schema type 'Map' from namespace
>     'http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap':
>     element 'item' is using anonymous type
>     declaration, anonymous types are not
>     supported with encoded SOAP.

Does this mean that I am not allowed to use Map when it comes a web service? I couldn't be satisfied with google results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer my own question;
You should not use java.util.Map as a return type if you want to make your web services consumable by .NET
http://wiki.apache.org/ws/FrontPage/Axis/DotNetInteropMapInfo